# Issue with Bootstrap (using React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I want a **margin** between my button (increment) and badge (bootstrap classes badge badge-primary).
The tutorial I am using is outdated and I am having trouble finding it online. What is the proper margin class to use (tutorial said m-2)

```
 render() {
//React.createElement('div')
return (
  //in curly braces any js statement is valid
  <div>
    <span className="badge badge-primary m-2">
      {this.formatCount()}
    </span>
    <button>Increment</button>
  </div>
);
}
```

And to be clear, the issue is in this exact snippet.

```
<span className="badge badge-primary m-2">
```

Thank you for any responses, I am a beginner :)

Comment: Which version of boostrap are you using? Can you please post a code snippet which reproduces your problem?

Comment: @MarkoGrešak in my package.json it says 3.4.1. I also did post a code snippet after which shows where I had the problem, what did you mean?

Comment: the `m-2` (utility classes) is a feature of Bootstrap 4. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 1):

With `m-2` you should have 0.5 rems of margin on all four sides of that span element. Are the `badge` and `badge-primary` classes being applied? I suggest using Google Chrome Dev tools => Elements tab => ".cls" button => add and remove classes to see how elements receive styles. Refer to Bootstrap spacing docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

EDIT:
It's also probably because the `span` element is an inline element, so try either adding class `d-block` or `d-inline-block` to see `m-2` apply, or change from `span` to a block-level element like `div`.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have already looked at the bootstrap docs, m-2 and mx-2 are not working for some reason. I changed span to div (resulted in error) and adding the d-block classes did not work, any idea why?

Comment: I noted in one of your previous comments that you're using Bootstrap 3.4.1. That is probably why the `m-2` class is not being applied as it was introduced Bootstrap 4. I haven't yet been able to find how to add margin using that version of Boostrap, so I would either install a later version or manually apply the style e.g. `style={{ margin: '0.5rem' }}`.

Comment: Now I have "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6" (found in package.json). m-2 still is not working.